# Google Drive API : List files in a specific folder

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I need to list all files in a drive specific folder. It's working but not really as expected.
I get the whole list of files that are in this folder even if the file has been removed and placed in the trash.

How can I only get the files that are really in this folder ?

```js
async listActiveSeries()
{
    let _RESULT = null;
    
    try
    {
        const auth = await this._makeClient();
        const googleDriveClient = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

        const response = await googleDriveClient.files.list
        ({
            pageSize: 150,
            q: `'${ID_OF_THE_FOLDER}' in parents`
        });

        if(response && response.data && response.data.files)
        {
            _RESULT = response.data.files;
        }
    }
    catch(ex)
    { console.log(ex); }
    
    return _RESULT;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list in only the specific folder.
- You don't want to include the files in the trashbox.

In this case, how about using `trashed=false` to the search query? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
q: `'${ID_OF_THE_FOLDER}' in parents`
```

#### To:

```
q: `'${ID_OF_THE_FOLDER}' in parents and trashed=false`
```

- By adding `trashed=false` as `AND`, the files in the trash box is not retrieved.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

Comment: Hi Tanaike :D
This isn't working for me. I still get trashed files with: q: "'" + folderID + "' in parents and trashed=false"

Comment: Changed it to this and still doesn't work: q: `'${folderID}' in parents and trashed=false`

Comment: @Robert M. First, I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Hi Tanaike :D This isn't working for me. I still get trashed files with: q: "'" + folderID + "' in parents and trashed=false"` and `Changed it to this and still doesn't work: q: '${folderID}' in parents and trashed=false`. I cannot understand your current script. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Robert M. So, can you post it as a new question? Because this is not your question and when I tested ``q: `'${ID_OF_THE_FOLDER}' in parents and trashed=false```, the files in the trash box are not retrieved. I apologize for this situation. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sure. But basically I changed my query to match your suggestion and still got trashed files.

Comment: @Robert M. Thank you for replying. From `Sure. But basically I changed my query to match your suggestion and still got trashed files.`, I would like to check your new question when I found your posted new question.